# Concurrency in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, concurrency

I am trying to learn - concurrency in java 8. Below are few versions with their performance-

```
List<Class1> getSequential(List<String> numList) {
    return numList
        .stream()
        .map(num -> getOneObjofClass1(num))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Sequential Time: 31.0 seconds

```
List<Class1> getConcurrentWithES(List<String> numList) {
    List<Class1> obj = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

        List<Future<Class1>> futures = 
            numList
                .stream()
                .map(num -> executorService.submit(() -> getOneObjofClass1(num)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Future<Class1> future : futures) {
            obj.add(future.get());
    return obj;
}
```

Concurrent Time: 6.0 seconds

```
List<Class1> getConcurrentWithCompletableFutures(List<String> numList) {
    List<Class1> obj = new ArrayList<Class1>();                           
    numList
        .stream()
        .map(num ->
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getOneObjofClass1(num)).thenApply(obj::add))
        .forEach(CompletableFuture::join);

    return obj;
}
```

Concurrent Time With Completable Futures: 21.0 seconds

```
List<Class1> getConcurrentWithParallelStreams(List<String> numList) {
    return numList
        .parallelStream()
        .map(num -> getOneObjofClass1(num))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Concurrent Time With Parallel Streams: 11.0 seconds.

Why are versions with completable futures and parallel streams not giving me good performance as compared to concurrency with Executor service. (Size of input list is 20 values)

Comment: You should probably explain how you set up the benchmark.

Comment: Or we can cut to the chase and say: please [read the instructions and then use JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) for microbenchmarking.

Comment: What `getOneObjofClass1` does?

Comment: The general rule of thumb is unless you have about 1000 or so items to process, or processing takes a "long" time (a least reasonable fraction of a millisecond), the overhead of dealing with the parallelisation is greater than its other benefits.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess: your `getOneObjofClass1` involves a blocking I/O operation. One call takes about 1.5 seconds to complete. Since the `commonPool`, on which the parallel stream reduction is done, only has as many threads as there are cores on your machine, whereas the executor service you create has 100 threads, there are more I/O requests in progress concurrently, so everything completes sooner.

Comment: @ bradimus and olsli I am running this program on 1.6GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 on Mac OS with java 8 installed and yes getOneObjofCLass1() is going to search something from web and then return object of Class1. @Bohemian yes I agree i should have more items but if getOneObjofClass1() is time consuming independent logic and i want to use multi threads to do it. I just want to understand whats going on inside like Marko Topolnik, is suggesting is making more sense.

Comment: Given your use case, the approach with Executor service makes the most sense, but you should rewrite it to avoid side effects in `map`. You should first collect a list of `Callable`s, then `invokeAll`. Or, if you want to handle the result as soon as a task is done, use `CompletionService`.